# How to get the dragged objects and the destination object from event.mimeData() in dropEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside

I'm dragging `QTableWidgetItem`s or `QTreeWidgetItem`s onto a `QTreeWidgetItem`. How can I fetch the dragged object(s) I'm dragging and dropping and how can I fetch the destination `QTreeWidgetItem`?

This is what I have (see `#COMMENTS`):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class TreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.header().setHidden(True)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)

        self.itemDropped = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

        item1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self, ['first tree folder'])
        item1.setData(1, QtCore.Qt.EditRole, 'first tree data')

        item2 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item1, ['second tree folder'])
        item2.setData(1, QtCore.Qt.EditRole, 'second tree data')        

        item3 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self, ['third tree folder'])
        item3.setData(1, QtCore.Qt.EditRole, 'third tree data')

        item1.setExpanded(True)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        """On drop, get the target and the dragged item(s)"""
        print 'drop!'
        if (event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')):
            source_widget = event.source()
            # HOW TO GET DESTINATION HERE?
            if isinstance(source_widget, QtGui.QTreeWidget):
                # HOW TO GET DRAGGED ITEMS HERE?
            if isinstance(source_widget, QtGui.QTableWidget):
                # HOW TO GET DRAGGED ITEMS HERE?
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        """Allow dragging from the tree and the table widgets"""
        if (event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')):
            source_widget = event.source()
            if isinstance(source_widget, QtGui.QTreeWidget):
                event.accept()  # Move!
            if isinstance(source_widget, QtGui.QTableWidget):
                event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


class Table(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(False)

        item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        item1.setText('first table file')
        item1.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, 'first table data')

        item2 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        item2.setText('second table file')
        item2.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, 'second table data')

        item3 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        item3.setText('third file')
        item3.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, 'third table data')

        self.setRowCount(3)
        self.setColumnCount(1)
        self.setItem(0, 0, item1)
        self.setItem(1, 0, item2)
        self.setItem(2, 0, item3)


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.tree_widget = TreeWidget()
        self.table = Table()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Folders'))
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tree_widget)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Files'))
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it in the end:

```
def dropEvent(self, event):
    """On drop, get the target and the dragged item(s)"""
    print 'drop!'
    if (event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')):
        source_widget = event.source()
        destination = self.itemAt(event.pos())
        if isinstance(source_widget, QtGui.QTreeWidget):
            selected_items = source_widget.selectedItems()
        if isinstance(source_widget, QtGui.QTableWidget):
            selected_items = []
            indexes = source_widget.selectionModel().selectedRows()
            column = 0
            for index in sorted(indexes):
                selected_items.append(source_widget.item(index.row(), column))
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```